# Java PreparedStatement for SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

Write appropriate Java statements that make a `PreparedStatement`, set the instructor `ID` to `10101` and then find the title of the course that the instructor taught with the `PreparedStatement` and execute the query. You can assume that a Connection object conn has already been created.

I understand how to make a prepared statement and execute a query. I am just unsure on how to do two queries in one

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(“update instructor set ID = 10101”); 
pStmt.setString(1,11111);
pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Batch Updates. Please check it in http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/batchupdate.html.

Or else:

If you want to send more than one command to DBMS in only one call, you need to round them with a BEGIN...END block. Please check the following example:

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE .... ;
  INSERT .... ;
  (...)
END;
```

Note that this is pseudo code.

It's possible to send more than one update, insert, delete, etc, if you use a block BEGIN...END; Some databases like Oracle accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// the '?' is a placeholder for values
final String sql = "UPDATE instructor SET ID = ?"; // you're probably missing a WHERE clause here, otherwise it will update every instructor to have the same ID
// send the query to the db server for it to prepare
final PreparedStatement updateInstructorIdPstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
// ... 

public void updateInstructorID(final int newId) throws SQLException {
    // set the newId as the parameter for this query execution
    updateInstructorIdPstmt.setInt(1, newId); // '1' means it's the first paramenter.
                                              // it could be 2 or 3 or whatever depending on which '?' it is in your statement
    // execute this update query
    updateInstructorIdPstmt.execute(); // executeUpdate() will return how many rows were updated, if you need to know that info
}
```

There are further ways to optimize this, but it should set you down the right path. Doing it similar to this way will allow you to just keep executing queries for that given preparedstatement. You can have multiple preparedstatement's, each with it's own query backing it.